# TfLite code compiling Successfully, but upon adding pico_add_extra_outputs() in CMakeLists.txt, got Error: Require 32 bit little-endian ELF

Tags: c++, linux, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi-pico

Here is my CMakeLists.txt. I am using cmake .. and make commands to build this example

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(TFLiteExample CXX C ASM)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tflite-dist/include/)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
pico_sdk_init()
# lib has 1 file: libtensorflowlite.so
ADD_LIBRARY(tensorflowlite SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET tensorflowlite PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tflite-dist/libs/linux_x64/libtensorflowlite.so)



# Add the source file to the project
add_executable(TFLiteExample main.cpp)

# Add the TensorFlow Lite headers to the include directories
target_link_libraries(TFLiteExample tensorflowlite)


pico_add_extra_outputs(TFLiteExample)
pico_enable_stdio_usb(${PROJECT_NAME} 1)
```

I get this error

```
[ 30%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
Scanning dependencies of target elf2uf2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/elf2uf2.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable elf2uf2
[100%] Built target elf2uf2
[ 35%] No install step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 40%] Completed 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 40%] Built target ELF2UF2Build
Scanning dependencies of target TFLiteExample
[ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TFLiteExample.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable TFLiteExample
ERROR: Require 32 bit little-endian ELF
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TFLiteExample.dir/build.make:90: TFLiteExample] Error 253
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'TFLiteExample'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1747: CMakeFiles/TFLiteExample.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I want to build .uf2 file for raspberry pi pico. But I am not able to.
Please comment you suggestions